# Low Texture Graphics in Mupen64

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I installed Mupen64plus in my system and tried to run Ocarina of Time.
Instead of the nostalgic polygonal graphics I saw low texture graphics where green turned to brown and Link's face missing. I had a similar problem when running Opensonic.

When I checked System Information it showed this

```
Driver Intel® 845G x86/MMX/SSE2 
Experience Standard
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have no such problem when playing Super Maryo Chronicles

Answer (score 0):

Try to install all the graphic plug-ins and see if the problem persists:

```
sudo apt-get install mupen64plus-video-all
```

If you still have problems, you can check if there are some specific drivers for your graphic cars,  which I think is an Intel integrated card.